# Cantor set exercise

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, dimension-theory-analysis

This is an exercise from Abbott's real analysis book. It's exercise 3.4.4.(b) on page 93. I couldn't find a definition of ''dimension'' in the book. The only thing I could find is something on page 77. It seems to say that if you "magnify" an object by a factor of $3$ and denote the dimension by $d$ then $3^d = $ size of the magnified object. Example: if the object is a square of length $1$ then scaling it by $3$ is $9$ times the square  $\implies$ $3^d = 9$ $\implies d=2$. I tried to apply this to this exercise:

Let $C$ now be the [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set): Let $C_0 = [0,1]$, $C_1= [0,3/8] \cup [5/8,1]$ and so on (remove the middle fourth in each step).

$C = \bigcap_n C_n$ is closed since it is an intersection of closed sets and it is bounded since it is contained in $[0,1]$ therefore $C$ is compact. It is perfect because it is closed and because it does not contain any isolated points: if $x \in C$ then for every $n$, $x \in C_n$ and since the endpoints of $C_n$ are in $C_n$ there is a point other than $x$ in $B(x, 2/8(2/3)^n) \cap C$.

The length of $C$ is $1$ minus everything that is removed: 
$$ 1- 1/4 -  2/8 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2/3)^k = 1-1/2 = 1/2$$

Its dimension is computed by starting with $[0,3]$ and noting that removing the middle fourth yields two intervals of length $11/8$. Using these to produce two Cantor sets yields two Cantor sets of length $11/8$ each. Therefore the dimension of the new Cantor set (Cantor set produced from $[0,3]$) is

$$ 3^d = 2 \times {11 \over 8} = {22 \over 8}$$

solving for the dimension of the Cantor set $d$:

$$ d = {\log {22\over 8}\over \log 3} = {\log 22 - \log 8 \over \log 3}$$

and I don't know how to simplify this expression further. Is this $d$ the dimension of the fat Cantor set?

**Edit** I founbd [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension). According to this the Hausdorff dimension should be $1$. So my calculation should be false.

I also found [this](http://www.learner.org/courses/mathilluminated/units/5/textbook/06.php). According to this, if $N$ is the number of self similar copies and $s$ is the scaling factor then $N= s^d$. I computed that there are ${22\over 8}$ self similar copies. So my calculation should be correct.

Comment: Where do you get the $(2/3)$s from? The length (or measure) of $C_n$ is $\left(\frac34\right)^n$, so can $C$ have positive measure?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DanielFischer The parts removed have lenghts $1/4$, $2 \times 1/8$, $4 \times 1 / 24$ , $8 \times 1/72$... so that the terms after $1/4$ are of the form $2/8 \times (2/3)^n$. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: The middle fourth of an interval of length $\ell$ has length $\frac14\ell$, so you remove $\frac14$, then $2\times \frac14\cdot \frac38 = \frac14\cdot \frac34$, then $2^2\times \frac14\cdot \frac{3^2}{8^2} = \frac14\cdot \frac{3^2}{4^2}$ etc.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh thanks, that was a mistake. If I do it with $2^k {1\over 4} (3/8)^k$ then the lenght is $0$. Did I get the dimension right?

Comment: @DanielFischer Did I get the dimension right?

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't. I don't know how the dimension is defined in your setting, but in the definition of dimension I'm used to, you have $V(r\cdot C) = r^d\cdot V(C)$, and scaling by $3/8$ gives you one half of $C$, so $$V\left(\frac38 C\right) = \left(\frac38\right)^dV(C) = \frac12V(C) \Rightarrow d = \frac{\log \frac12}{\log \frac38} = \frac{\log 2}{\log \frac83}$$ for me.

Comment: @DanielFischer There was no explicit definition given, only examples. What is $V$? At first I thought it was volume but $V(C) = 0$ if $C$ is the Cantor set.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know where the $3/8$ come from in your computation. If I do it I get that magnifying the Cantor set by a factor of $3$ yields $2 \times {9 \over 8}$ copies of Cantor sets. Then my guess for the dimension $d$ would be the solution to $$ 3^d = {18 \over 8}$$

Comment: $V(C)$ is the $d$-dimensional volume of $C$. The $3/8$ comes from the fact that if you scale $C$ with a factor of $3/8$, you get one half of $C$, the part in the interval $[0,1/2]$ (which is actually contained in $[0,3/8]$). If you scale by $3$, you get two copies each of $9/8$ linear length, but for the $d$-dimensional content, you have to raise that to the $d$-th power, $$3^d = 2\cdot \left(\frac98\right)^d.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot, I finally get it. In the example I didn't see that you had to raise both sides to the power of $d$ because in the case of the normal Cantor set the $9/8$ is $1$ so that it's $3^d =2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Does this dimension have a name? I looked at Hausdorff dimension on Wikipedia but it seems to be different.

Comment: What are you looking for with the bounty? It looks like Daniel Fischer's comments had you satisfied earlier in the year. This is Hausdorff dimension, incidentally-this method of computation is just a step or two removed from the definition.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I don't get this at all. I can't make sense of the definition of Hausdorff dimension on Wikipedia and I don't know if my new computation using the pseudo-definition from the book is correct. With this bounty I am looking for someone who (1) will proof-read what I posted above and (2) will either give me a clearer definition than that on Wiki or, alternatively, explain the def. on Wiki to me using this exercise as an example.

Comment: According to the [list of fractals by Hausdorff dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension), your $C$, where in each step you remove the middle fourth, has Hausdorff dimension $$-\frac{\log 2}{\log \frac{1-\gamma}{2}},$$ with $\gamma = \frac{1}{4}$. That is, the dimension is $$-\frac{\log 2}{\log \frac{3}{8}} = \frac{\log 2}{\log \frac{8}{3}}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your description

> remove the middle fourth in each step

doesn't match the linked construction. That probably explains a lot of the confusion.

---

The Hausdorff dimension of a subset $S$ of a metric space is defined as

$$\dim_{\mathcal{H}} S := \inf \left\{ d > 0 : \mathcal{H}^d(S) = 0 \right\},$$

where $\mathcal{H}^d$ is the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure. The Hausdorff measures have the properties

- $\mathcal{H}^d(S) < \infty \land d < \delta \implies \mathcal{H}^\delta(S) = 0$, and
- $\mathcal{H}^d(s) > 0 \land \delta < d\implies \mathcal{H}^\delta(S) = \infty$,

so we have $\mathcal{H}^d(S) = 0$ for all $d > \dim_{\mathcal{H}} S$ and $\mathcal{H}^\delta(S) = \infty$ for all $0 \leqslant \delta < \dim_{\mathcal{H}} S$. The Hausdorff measure in the dimension of $S$, $\mathcal{H}^{\dim_{\mathcal{H}} S}(S)$, can be $0$, $\infty$, or a positive real number.

---

In the construction of the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set, in the $n$-th step one removes an interval of length $2^{-2n}$ from each of the $2^{n-1}$ intervals of $C_n$, and thus the total (Lebesgue) measure of the removed sets is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{2n}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2},$$

leaving a fat Cantor set of (Lebesgue) measure $\frac{1}{2}$. Now it is a (not entirely trivial) fact that on $\mathbb{R}^k$ the $k$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is a constant multiple of the Lebesgue measure (both are translation-invariant measures, and one has to verify that the unit cube [or unit ball] has finite nonzero $k$-dimensional Hausdorff measure for the conclusion). Thus the $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^1(C)$ is a positive real number, which implies that the Hausdorff-dimension of $C$ is $1$.

This fat Cantor set is not self-similar, since the ratio of the length of the removed middle parts to the length of the containing intervals depends on the step number. In the first step, the ratio is $\frac{4^{-1}}{1} = \frac{1}{4}$, in the second, the ratio is $\frac{4^{-2}}{3/8} = \frac{1}{6}$, in the third, it is $\frac{4^{-3}}{5/32} = \frac{1}{10}$. After the $n$-th step, $C_n$ consists of $2^n$ intervals each of length $\frac{2^n+1}{2^{2n+1}}$, and the ratio of the part removed in the next step to the intervals is $\frac{2^{-(2n+2)}}{(2^n+1)/2^{-(2n+1)}} = \frac{1}{2(2^n+1)}$.

Since the set is not self-similar, the dimension cannot be determined by the [self-similarity method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension#Self-similar_sets). But, since the set has positive Lebesgue measure, its (Hausdorff) dimension can be determined from that.

---

In the construction where in each step the middle fourth of the intervals is removed, we obtain a self-similar Cantor set of Lebesgue measure $0$. Each $\tilde{C}_{n+1}$ has $\frac{3}{4}$ the Lebesgue measure of $\tilde{C}_n$, since always one fourth of the set is removed, so $\lambda(\tilde{C}_n) = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$, and hence $\lambda(\tilde{C}) = 0$. But

$$\tilde{C} = \frac{3}{8}\cdot\tilde{C} \cup \left(1 - \frac{3}{8}\cdot\tilde{C}\right),$$

where the union is disjoint (and the parts even have positive distance), so for the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure we have

$$\mathcal{H}^d(\tilde{C}) = 2\cdot \left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^d\cdot \mathcal{H}^d(\tilde{C}),$$

and *if* $\mathcal{H}^d(\tilde{C})$ is a nonzero real number, we have

$$2\cdot \left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^d = 1,$$

and that is equivalent to

$$d = \frac{\log 2}{\log \frac{8}{3}}.$$

The [self-similarity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension#Self-similar_sets) tells us that the Hausdorff dimension of $\tilde{C}$ is $d = \frac{\log 2}{\log \frac{8}{3}}$ even without knowing whether $\mathcal{H}^d(\tilde{C})$ is zero, infinite or finite and positive.

Comment: Thank you now I understand almost. One question: Why is there $1- {3 \over 8}$ in the expression $\tilde{C}$? Starting with $C$ and removing the middle fourth should leave two sets of equal size, ${3 \over 8}$, on each side. Why is the right side ${5\over 8}$?

Comment: The expression means $$1 - \frac{3}{8}\tilde{C} = \left\{ 1 - \frac{3}{8}y : y \in \tilde{C}\right\},$$ you get the right part of $\tilde{C}$ by scaling $\tilde{C}$ by the factor of $\frac{3}{8}$ and then applying the transformation $t \mapsto 1-t$ to that. Maybe it would have been clearer if I had written $$\frac{3}{8}\tilde{C} + \frac{5}{8},$$ instead of the transformation $t\mapsto 1-t$ one could also use the translation by $\frac{5}{8}$, since the set is symmetric about the middle. The _length_ of the right half is $\frac{3}{8}$ too, its left endpoint is located at $\frac{5}{8}$.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand that. One more thing that I don't understand yet: If the formula is $N = s^d$ and the scaling factor is $3$ (because instead of using $[0,1]$ to construct the Cantor set one now uses $[0,3]$) then why is your $s$ not $3$?

Comment: I see that there is a difference: I scaled by $3$ first, like the book did for the cubes. But you first took out the middle fourth and then used two intervals of length $3/8$. Why is it clear that one can't scale first?

Comment: You can scale first, but one cannot scale by an arbitrary factor (when using the self-similarity). One needs to scale by a factor such that either one part of the scaled set is _congruent_ to the original, or the scaled set is congruent to one part of the original figure. When removing the middle fourths, the scaling factor must be a power of $\frac{3}{8}$ to achieve that. Generally, if you remove the middle $\gamma$ part, the scaling factor must be a power of $\frac{1-\gamma}{2}$ to get the congruence.